# How do I add a class on ng-click from layout?

Tags: angularjs

Here is the page layout:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li ng-click="SetActiveMenuForPersonalInfo();">
            <a href="../Account/#/PersonalInfo">@Translate("MY_ACCOUNT")<a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

When a user clicks on my account, they get this: http://plnkr.co/edit/gJko3umteXXEye7o9StR?p=preview

This is the function in the controller:

```
$scope.SetActiveMenuForPersonalInfo = function () {
    $scope.activeMenu = 'Settings';
    $scope.activeLink = "PersonalInfo";
    console.log("Active menu: ",$scope.activeMenu);
}
```

How can i change `$scope.activeMenu` and `$scope.activeLink` when a user clicks on "My Account" that is on Layout? The console prints "Settings" for `$scope.activeMenu` so it means that it's in functions, but nothing is happening . . .  Maybe it's because I put `$scope.activeMenu` in a function?

Comment: in your plnkr, active-link doesnt work. Replace this with activeLink

Comment: its works...it just need 'active-link' but thats not a point because i need to pass value from Layout

Comment: Anyway, if I understand correctly you want the bars to be red like they are when clicking contact/about etc?

Comment: yes but from layout...somehow when i click it on layout its not working...$scope.activeMenu is empty....

Comment: What do you mean with 'on layout'?

Comment: i mean i have menu on layout...and in that menu i have <li ng-click="SetActiveMenuForPersonalInfo();"><a href="../Account/#/PersonalInfo">@Translate("MY_ACCOUNT")</a></li>

Comment: Do you have the right controller defined for your menu layout part?

Comment: how u mean right controller?

Comment: When i put $scope outside of function i get what i want but when i put it in function i dont get anything

Comment: I've updated your plnkr in my answer, perhaps this is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plnkr the css for active-link was missing, and I wrapped the assigning of the clicked link in a function.

Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/RaAFp2naJdKKR7RZFbqV?p=preview) updated plnkr.

The function is pretty basic:

```
$scope.changeActiveLink = function(link) {
    $scope.activeLink = link;
}
```

Now the links are green when clicked. This is what you wanted right? Well, maybe a different color, but the principle is the same.

If you want to remove the green when clicking 'contact' or 'about', you could wrap those in a function aswell which would look like:

```
$scope.changeActiveMenu = function(menu) {
    if($scope.activeMenu == 'Settings' && menu != 'Settings') {
        $scope.activeLink = '';
    }

    $scope.activeMenu = menu;
}
```

**Update**

I Finally understand what you mean, I think.. By clicking the link you change view, thus re-instantiating your controller. This is why the activeMenu is empty. If you create a service and store the currently active menu in there, it won't be empty.

I have updated the plnkr to include a service. I can't fully test it as I haven't got your whole project code, but with this as guideline you should be able to get it to work!

Comment: I dont have problem with that menu...i have problem when user try to click on menu from layout then its not working because $scope is empty

Comment: I think I got what you want now, check my updated answer

Comment: yes i think that is...its just that i dont know how to create a service...i tried but without success

Comment: can u help me to write service?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try stop the event propagation? If it is not working this way, try to add it to the child  elements.

```
$scope.SetActiveMenuForPersonalInfo = function ($event)
{
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.activeMenu = 'Settings';
    $scope.activeLink = "PersonalInfo";
    console.log("Active menu: ",$scope.activeMenu);
}
```

Comment: i tried like this SetActiveMenuForPersonalInfo($event); but its not working

Comment: and did you try to add stoppropagation to child <a> elements. or try bind ng-click directive to  <a> tags not to <li>. you can style <a> to perform like an <li> box

Comment: i get this error : Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined